# Sequelize does not recognize table with camelCase name when using raw query

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am stuck using a raw query in sequelize to query data from a table with the camel case name.
The codes look like this

```
 const activeProducts = await sequelize.query(
  `SELECT ap.*, pd.stack_id stack_id, pd.channel_id channel_id, pd.product_type product_type  FROM active_products ap
  join productDefinitions pd on ap.product_id = pd.id
  WHERE active = \'active\'

  `,
  { type: QueryTypes.SELECT }
);
console.log(activeProducts)
return activeProducts;
```

It seems that sequelize does not recognize the table name with camel case letter. Instead of finding 'productDefinitions', it look for 'productdefinitions' and here is the output

```
Error: relation "productdefinitions" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using Postgres. Try to wrap the table name with `"`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Quoting the table name?

```
SELECT ap.*, pd.stack_id stack_id, pd.channel_id channel_id, pd.product_type product_type  FROM active_products ap
  join "productDefinitions" pd on ap.product_id = pd.id
  WHERE active = \'active\'
```